# python doesn't write if call from php

Tags: php, python, exec

I have a python script writetest.py with the following:

```
print "mark1"
with open("/testfile.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("Hello World")
print "mark2"
```

When I call the scrip in the shell, it work and adds "Hello World" the testfile.txt.  When I call it using the php exec command, it doesn't write:

```
exec('python writetest.py', $output, $return_var);
print_r($output);
print_r($return_var);
```

Which prints:

```
Array ( [0] => mark1 )
1
```

My python script runs but stops at the open code.

Comment: It could be a permission issue. Does the user that runs the web server have permission to read/write to that file?

Comment: You do not need `myfile.close()` when you use `with` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aynber pointed out, it was a permissions issue.  I gave the web server user write access and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think there is quote issue in your code

> exec('python writetest.py")

Once you fix that, try again.
If still not working I would suggest

```
exec('python writetest.py', $output , $return_var)
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Then print output and return_var by print_r for debugging purpose

```
print_r($output);
print_r($return_var);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Edited the original question